# Is the punctuation of generational suffixes dropped when they occur at the end of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Is the punctuation of generational suffixes (e.g. "Jr.", "Sr.") dropped when they occur at the end of a sentence?

For instance,

> I liked Gerald Rudolph Ford Jr.

The obvious answer seems to be yes, since having two periods back-to-back seems incorrect. If that is the case, however, it seems strange because there appears to be "information loss" in that the shortening of the generation suffix and the end of the sentence both share the same punctuation.

Comment: The CMOS FAQ [asks](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Punctuation/faq0040.html) *Why, after a lifetime (I trust) of never encountering two periods in a row, do readers suddenly think this might be a good idea?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chicago Manual of Style, Section 6.117, "Abbreviation-ending periods with other punctuation" states:

> When an expression (such as an abbreviation) that takes a period ends
>   a sentence, no additional period follows (see 6.14). Of course, when
>   any other mark of punctuation is needed immediately after the period,
>   both the period and the additional mark appear.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, it was during idle browsing while waiting for a meeting to start...

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, the '.' in 'Jr.' is already redundant, so there isn't information loss unless the abbreviation happens to match another word.

Comment: I'm curious why you think the period is redundant. I thought it was incorrect to just say "Gerald Rudolph Ford Jr was president" for example.

Comment: I've managed to find a style guide endorsing the omission of full stops after abbreviations where ambiguity isn't an issue. You need to add such a reference, especially with such a contentious issue.